# Can I multiply the result of a SELECT query by an integer within a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, where-clause, integer-division

In this problem, I am finding musicians who play 'many' instruments - i.e. more than half of the total number of instruments.

I have a query to retrieve the total number of instruments. I cannot hardcode this value (e.g. using num_instruments > 6). I must use the query to retrieve the number of instruments and remove all doubt.

```
create or replace view instrument_count
as
select count(distinct instrument)
from instrument_list;
```

Here is what my query looks like:

```
-- Which performers play more than half of the total instruments? 
create or replace view multi_performers
as
select *
from performers_instruments
where n_instruments > ((1/2) * (select count from instrument_count))
;
```

However, instead of returning values above 6, it returns regular values. It seems to have no effect.
OUTPUT:

```
music=# select * from multi_performers limit 10;
 performer | n_instruments 
-----------+---------------
         1 |             2
         3 |             1
         4 |             2
         5 |             3
         6 |             6
         7 |             5
         8 |             5
         9 |             1
        10 |             6
        11 |             3
```

When I do NOT multiply the select statement, it acts normally - i.e. if the subquery returns '12', then it will return no values as nobody plays more than the maximum number of instruments (which is 12).

```
-- Which performers play more than half of the total instruments? 
create or replace view multi_performers
as
select *
from performers_instruments
where n_instruments > (select count from instrument_count)
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
music=# select * from multi_performers limit 10;
 performer | n_instruments 
-----------+---------------
(0 rows)
```

Any idea how to implement the requirement of 'more than half'? I.e. how to multiply the result of a subquery and use it within a larger query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integer division.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE)

```
SELECT 1/2;  -- 0 !
```

Try instead:

```sql
select *
from   performers_instruments
where  n_instruments > (select count(distinct instrument) * 0.5 from instrument_list);
```

Also cutting out the view `instrument_count`, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I was being foolish and totally forgot 1/2 will have a different result to using a float. Thank you so much.